# Still LookupError in punkt after putting the file into site-packages file

Tags: python, nltk

I was trying to tokenize the text i got from web through this:

```
import nltk,re,pprint
from nltk import word_tokenize
from urllib import request
#...getting file from web
tokens=word_tokenize(raw) #raw is the text from web
```

And then LookupError comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
    tokens = word_tokenize(raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 129, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 106, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load("tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle".format(language))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 752, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 877, in _open
    return find(path_, path + [""]).open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 585, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  [0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load [93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle[0m
 Searched in:
    - '/Users/ic/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
```

I realize this might occur because i haven't downloaded 'punkt', and then  i tried to download from python:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

but the result comes as follows:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection
[nltk_data]     refused>
False
```

I think maybe internet connection has some problem? 
**So i also downloaded punkt package from web and put it into the nltk file in my site-packages.
But still the same problem i had at the first beginning occurred. Don't what to do about this now LOL! Any advice!**

Answer (score 0):

I think i knida solve the problem by simply spliting words into list!! DONE!